# Java Jakarta API from basic to bearer

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee, basic-authentication, bearer-token

I am new to Java Jakarta development, please could someone tell me how to convert authentication type in existing Java Jakarta-ee API from basic-auth to bearer-token, does it need a lot of effort?

I searched in internet, it seems it uses specific libraries.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don’t have the code the vendor requested 10 days working days, does this worth that time or this is only small configuration?